# Exercise 4.3.25 from Linear Algebra by Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $c_{jk}$ denote the cofactor of the row $j$, column $k$ entry of the matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}(F)$.

(a) Prove that if $B$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing column $k$ by $e_j$, then $\det(B)= c_{jk}$.

We know fro the hypothesis in the question that $c_{jk} = (-1)^{j + k}\det(\tilde{A}_{jk})$, where $\tilde{A}_{jk}$ is obtained from $A$ by deleting $j$th row and $k$th column. Also, using the cofactor expansion  along the $k$th column of $B$, $\det(B) = (-1)^{j+k} \det(\tilde{B}_{jk})$. All columns of $B$ except for $k$th column are the same with ones of $A$. Thus, $\det(\tilde{B}_{jk}) = \det(\tilde{A}_{jk})$, and this finishes the proof.

(b) Show that for $1 \ge j \ge n$, we have 
$$A \pmatrix {c_{j1} \\ {c_{j2}} \\ . \\ . \\ {c_{jn}}} = \det(A) \cdot e_j.$$
Hint: Apply Cramer's rule to $Ax = e_j$.

I know that $\det(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{jk}A_{jk}$ by definition. This implies that $e_j^t \cdot A  \cdot \pmatrix {c_{j1} \\ {c_{j2}} \\ . \\ . \\ {c_{jn}}} = \det(A)$. But I am stuck here, and I don't know how to apply the Cramer's rule here. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: see https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_4-3-25?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link